# Email-to-activity processing - not working

Tags: civimail, activities

I'm having trouble getting the email to activity processing to work. (Wordpress 4.4.4 and Civi 4.6.4) I keep getting this error:

```
Could not connect to MailStore for XXX@domain.org@imap.gmail.com&lt;p&gt;Error message: &lt;pre&gt;An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server: imap.gmail.com:993.&lt;/pre&gt;&lt;p&gt;

 $backTrace = #0 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(322): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(184): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not connect to MailStore for xxxx@domain.org@imap.gm...")
#2 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(111): CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::_process(FALSE, Object(CRM_Core_DAO_MailSettings))
#3 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(379): CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::processActivities()
#4 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_fetch_activities((Array:1))
#5 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#6 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("job", "fetch_activities", (Array:1), NULL)
#7 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(131): civicrm_api("job", "fetch_activities", (Array:1))
#8 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(110): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#9 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.php(155): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJobById("3")
#10 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(178): CRM_Admin_Page_Job->browse(NULL, NULL)
#11 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.php(140): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#12 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Admin_Page_Job->run((Array:3), NULL)
#13 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#14 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#15 /myfolder/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1189): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#16 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#17 /myfolder/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#18 /myfolder/wp-admin/admin.php(236): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
```

We use google apps to host our mail and I've read through the posts on here already regarding that set up. I don't think it's google apps that's tripping things up. I get this same error message with any email set up I try.  Here's what I've done to try and narrow down the problem - all of these result in the same  error "could not connect to MailStore"

- Used emails hosted through GoDaddy and Hostmonster.
- Tried both IMAP and POP3 settings
- Turned on and off SSL
- Cleaned the email accounts I was testing (i.e. they only had one or two emails in the account)
- To see if a different error would populate, purposefully used the wrong password.

Can anyone suggest what I might need to look for? I'm not sure I know what the rest of the backtrace means....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like firewall is blocking port 993. Do you use outlook or a desktop email program with imap? Does it work there? Do you know how to use telnet to test - can you telnet to port 993?

Comment: I didn't know how to test but a google search got me what I needed (thanks, another tool in my belt). I ran an imap (993) test and get the following result: "OK Gimap ready for requests" so I'm guessing that yes, it works.

Comment: Just checking you tried that test FROM THE SERVER?

Comment: Whoopsie, no I hadn't, which it's clearly the important part (thus the reference to a firewall, right?) When I try to run the telnet imap test (on the server this time ;), the connection just times out. Is this a sign it's a firewall. I imagine I have to contact my host at this point?